# SQL Query to split one column's data into multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to built a PHP page with an HTML table that will populate the outcome of this query. Note that the values i want to split into multiple columns are all in the same column originally.... "lastvalue" this is what makes it difficult to write "ONE" query that will output my desired results.

Table Layout:

```
name                                    | key_                  |  lastvalue
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI1             | activeChannels[33]    |   1
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI2             | activeChannels[34]    |   1
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI3             | activeChannels[35]    |   2
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI4             | activeChannels[36]    |   1
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI5             | activeChannels[37]    |   2
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI6             | activeChannels[38]    |   1
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI7             | activeChannels[39]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL5/DI8             | activeChannels[40]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI1             | activeChannels[41]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI2             | activeChannels[42]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI3             | activeChannels[43]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI4             | activeChannels[44]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI5             | activeChannels[45]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI6             | activeChannels[46]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI7             | activeChannels[47]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL6/DI8             | activeChannels[48]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI1             | activeChannels[49]    |   23
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI2             | activeChannels[50]    |   1
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI3             | activeChannels[51]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI4             | activeChannels[52]    |   9
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI5             | activeChannels[53]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI6             | activeChannels[54]    |   2
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI7             | activeChannels[55]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL7/DI8             | activeChannels[56]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI1             | activeChannels[57]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI2             | activeChannels[58]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI3             | activeChannels[59]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI4             | activeChannels[60]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI5             | activeChannels[61]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI6             | activeChannels[62]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI7             | activeChannels[63]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 SL8/DI8             | activeChannels[64]    |   0
Active Calls per T1 Totals:             | activeChannels[999    |   42
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI1  | statusLayer2[33]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI2  | statusLayer2[34]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI3  | statusLayer2[35]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI4  | statusLayer2[36]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI5  | statusLayer2[37]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI6  | statusLayer2[38]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI7  | statusLayer2[39]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL5/DI8  | statusLayer2[40]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI1  | statusLayer2[41]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI2  | statusLayer2[42]      |  Awaiting Establishment
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI3  | statusLayer2[43]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI4  | statusLayer2[44]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI5  | statusLayer2[45]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI6  | statusLayer2[46]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI7  | statusLayer2[47]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL6/DI8  | statusLayer2[48]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI1  | statusLayer2[49]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI2  | statusLayer2[50]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI3  | statusLayer2[51]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI4  | statusLayer2[52]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI5  | statusLayer2[53]      |  Awaiting Establishment
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI6  | statusLayer2[54]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI7  | statusLayer2[55]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL7/DI8  | statusLayer2[56]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI1  | statusLayer2[57]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI2  | statusLayer2[58]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI3  | statusLayer2[59]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI4  | statusLayer2[60]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI5  | statusLayer2[61]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI6  | statusLayer2[62]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI7  | statusLayer2[63]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) SL8/DI8  | statusLayer2[64]      |  Active
DS1 Datalink layer Status (L2) Totals:  | statusLayer2[999]     |  30 Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI1  | statusLayer1[33]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI2  | statusLayer1[34]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI3  | statusLayer1[35]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI4  | statusLayer1[36]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI5  | statusLayer1[37]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI6  | statusLayer1[38]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI7  | statusLayer1[39]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL5/DI8  | statusLayer1[40]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI1  | statusLayer1[41]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI2  | statusLayer1[42]      |  Lost Framing
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI3  | statusLayer1[43]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI4  | statusLayer1[44]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI5  | statusLayer1[45]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI6  | statusLayer1[46]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI7  | statusLayer1[47]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL6/DI8  | statusLayer1[48]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI1  | statusLayer1[49]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI2  | statusLayer1[50]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI3  | statusLayer1[51]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI4  | statusLayer1[52]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI5  | statusLayer1[53]      |  Lost Framing
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI6  | statusLayer1[54]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI7  | statusLayer1[55]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL7/DI8  | statusLayer1[56]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI1  | statusLayer1[57]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI2  | statusLayer1[58]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI3  | statusLayer1[59]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI4  | statusLayer1[60]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI5  | statusLayer1[61]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI6  | statusLayer1[62]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI7  | statusLayer1[63]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) SL8/DI8  | statusLayer1[64]      |  Active
DS1 Physical layer Status (L1) Totals:  | statusLayer1[999]     |  30 Active
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI1           | frameErrors[33]       |   22
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI2           | frameErrors[34]       |   62
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI3           | frameErrors[35]       |   64
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI4           | frameErrors[36]       |   66
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI5           | frameErrors[37]       |   57
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI6           | frameErrors[38]       |   59
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI7           | frameErrors[39]       |   66
Framing Errors per T1 SL5/DI8           | frameErrors[40]       |   64
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI1           | frameErrors[41]       |   68
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI2           | frameErrors[42]       |   68
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI3           | frameErrors[43]       |   65
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI4           | frameErrors[44]       |   75
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI5           | frameErrors[45]       |   64
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI6           | frameErrors[46]       |   69
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI7           | frameErrors[47]       |   68
Framing Errors per T1 SL6/DI8           | frameErrors[48]       |   58
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI1           | frameErrors[49]       |   194
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI2           | frameErrors[50]       |   196
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI3           | frameErrors[51]       |   185
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI4           | frameErrors[52]       |   180
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI5           | frameErrors[53]       |   0
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI6           | frameErrors[54]       |   199
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI7           | frameErrors[55]       |   59
Framing Errors per T1 SL7/DI8           | frameErrors[56]       |   66
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI1           | frameErrors[57]       |   28
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI2           | frameErrors[58]       |   47
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI3           | frameErrors[59]       |   43
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI4           | frameErrors[60]       |   41
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI5           | frameErrors[61]       |   48
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI6           | frameErrors[62]       |   42
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI7           | frameErrors[63]       |   47
Framing Errors per T1 SL8/DI8           | frameErrors[64]       |   45
Framing Errors per T1 Totals:           | frameErrors[999]      |  2415
```

And here is the outcome I would like:

```
port        | layer1        |   layer2                  | freaming_errors   | active_calls
T1 SL5/DI1  | Active        |   Active                  | 22                | 1
T1 SL5/DI2  | Active        |   Active                  | 62                | 1
T1 SL5/DI3  | Active        |   Active                  | 64                | 2
T1 SL5/DI4  | Active        |   Active                  | 66                | 1
T1 SL5/DI5  | Active        |   Active                  | 57                | 2
T1 SL5/DI6  | Active        |   Active                  | 59                | 1
T1 SL5/DI7  | Active        |   Active                  | 66                | 0
T1 SL5/DI8  | Active        |   Active                  | 64                | 0
T1 SL6/DI1  | Active        |   Active                  | 68                | 0
T1 SL6/DI2  | Lost Framing  |   Awaiting Establishment  | 68                | 0
T1 SL6/DI3  | Active        |   Active                  | 65                | 0
T1 SL6/DI4  | Active        |   Active                  | 75                | 0
T1 SL6/DI5  | Active        |   Active                  | 64                | 0
T1 SL6/DI6  | Active        |   Active                  | 69                | 0
T1 SL6/DI7  | Active        |   Active                  | 68                | 0
T1 SL6/DI8  | Active        |   Active                  | 58                | 0
T1 SL7/DI1  | Active        |   Active                  | 194               | 23
T1 SL7/DI2  | Active        |   Active                  | 196               | 1
T1 SL7/DI3  | Active        |   Active                  | 185               | 0
T1 SL7/DI4  | Active        |   Active                  | 180               | 9
T1 SL7/DI5  | Lost Framing  |   Awaiting Establishment  | 0                 | 0
T1 SL7/DI6  | Active        |   Active                  | 199               | 2
T1 SL7/DI7  | Active        |   Active                  | 59                | 0
T1 SL7/DI8  | Active        |   Active                  | 66                | 0
T1 SL8/DI1  | Active        |   Active                  | 28                | 0
T1 SL8/DI2  | Active        |   Active                  | 47                | 0
T1 SL8/DI3  | Active        |   Active                  | 43                | 0
T1 SL8/DI4  | Active        |   Active                  | 41                | 0
T1 SL8/DI5  | Active        |   Active                  | 48                | 0
T1 SL8/DI6  | Active        |   Active                  | 42                | 0
T1 SL8/DI7  | Active        |   Active                  | 47                | 0
T1 SL8/DI8  | Active        |   Active                  | 45                | 0
T1 Totals:  | 30 Active     |   30 Active               | 2415              | 42
```

any thoughts?.....Thanks

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell which string is actually stored in which column. Anyways, though MySQL is powerful, this might be easier if you fetch all results and sort them out in PHP.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not clear what the division of columns is in your sample data.

Comment: Paul i tried that and i actually have another post that explains the multiple issues i have in my php code with nested whiles and separate "select" statements. I believe you replied with an attempt to merge all the different select statements together.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841847/populate-html-table-with-mysql-data-multiple-queries

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a complex combination of the `SUBSTR` and `LOCATE` functions that are in MYSQL.

For details on `SUBSTR` [click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr).

For details on `LOCATE` [click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate).

Comment: I can use the SUBSTR function to gather the last 10 degits to output the port name. However, how do I split the "lastvalue" column into 4 different columns for each port?

Comment: I've also tried looking at CASE statements.....breaking my head over this....cant believe something so simple is turning into this degree of difficulty.